# How do I transponse a pair of excel columns in such a manner that the data appears side by side and not up and down?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose, excel-2016

This is what I want to do, is there a simple way for me to do the same?

[image]

Comment: Copy then paste special transpose will take columns to rows or vv.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you say what you have tried so far plz? BTW the short answer to your question is 'no' there isn't a really simple way to do it as far as I know, but there is a reasonably straightforward one by formula.

Comment: I only tried using transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

[image]

## Option 1: Without `OFFSET`

Due to the volatile character of `OFFSET`, I revised my previous answer (option 2) which does no longer use `OFFSET`. More complex, but does  consume lesser resources.

`D4` features `=CHOOSE(MOD(COLUMN(),2)+1,INDEX($A$3:$A$5,ROUNDUP((COLUMN()-COLUMN($C$4))/2,0),MOD(COLUMN(),2)),INDEX($B$3:$B$5,ROUNDUP((COLUMN()-COLUMN($C$4))/2,0),MOD(COLUMN();2)))`

- `CHOOSE` determines, whether the result should derive from column `A` or `B` (see the different anchors in both `INDEX` formulas. Apart from that, both formulas are equal.
- The `INDEX` formula is explained in *Option 2*.

## Option 2: With `OFFSET`

Here is a solution with the `OFFSET` function, driven by `COLUMN`.

`D4` features the following formula

```
=OFFSET($A$2,ROUNDUP((COLUMN()-COLUMN($C$4))/2,0),MOD(COLUMN(),2))
```

**Breakdown**

- `OFFSET`(*anchor*, *rows*, *columns*)
- *anchor*: first cell of the headline row
- *rows*: takes column of current cell and subtracts the column of the labeled cell (here "Output:") to get a sequence of ongoing numbers. As you are interested in the result of two adjacent cells, I divide the result by two. To get an integer value, I round the result up. This way, the source row is incremented by every two columns.
- *columns*: takes the column of the current cell divides it by two and uses the result to determine whether we take the content of the first or second column.

Comment: I used `CHOOSE` in *Option 1* to avoid a **spill-over error**. I do not have access to **Excel 2016**, which does not work with spillovers. So, maybe CHOOSE and two INDEX formulas would not be necessary there. You may also come along with one INDEX formula, that features an anchor like `$A$3:$B$5`. Unfortunately, I cannot test it.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know if I can tag you here in the comments, but this was really helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

Select and copy your data.

Right-click in the cell where you want it to be

From the options popping up, click on the one that says Transpose(T) (4th option from the left)

Below is an image to illustrate.

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to do what the questioner asked for as it provides the result in two rows not in one.